# My html5 app fail to display model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I'm using angularJS to do some custom filter work, but it failed to display model information at the first stage.

```
<html lang="en" data-ng-app="myApp">
<Head>
    <title>Custom filter</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head> 
<body>   
<div data-ng-init="varNum=0">
    <p>
        <label for="number">Enter number from 1 to 99:</label>
        <input type="number" data-ng-model="varNum" id="number"/>
    </p>
    <p>Your number: {{ varNum }}</p>
</div> 
<script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/appromannumber.js"></script>
</body>   
</html>
```

appromannumber.js

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.filter("myFilter", function (){
    return function(myNum) {
        var formatedNumber = "";
        switch(myNum) {
             0:formatedNumber="zero";break;    
        return formatedNumber;
        }
    });
```

**But if I remove the value of ng-app, like data-ng-app = "", it will start to display the varNum. I have no idea why this happen.**

Comment: In chrome dev tools, check if you don't have any error in console

Comment: The problem solved, I missed a }; in the js

Comment: without `case` your `switch` statement working ?

Answer (score 0):

Should not work angular without bootstrap module means without `ng-app="moduleName"`. I suspect that you miss something else and I mentioned bellow some problem in your code that may will help you

in your filter you missed

> 1. `case` in `switch` statement. need `case 0:` instead of `0:...`
> 2. `return formatedNumber;` this statement is unreachable. should use after `switch` statement

you can try like:

```
app.filter("myFilter", function (){
    return function(myNum) {
        var formatedNumber = "";
        switch(myNum) {
             case 0:formatedNumber="zero";break; 
             case 1:formatedNumber="One";break; 
        }
        return formatedNumber;
    };
});
```

and in html:

```
<div data-ng-init="varNum=0">
    <p>
        <label for="number">Enter number from 1 to 99:</label>
        <input type="number" data-ng-model="varNum" id="number"/>
    </p>
    <p>Your number: {{ varNum | myFilter }}</p> // shown filtered value
</div>
```